# Bearer authentication working from postman but not from android app

Tags: java, c#, android, retrofit2, bearer-token

I am experiencing a strange issue, it's a bit complex, but I'll do my best to explain it.

I have a CMS which runs on ASP.Net Core 2.2. I've lately added to the cookie authentication also Bearer authentication with JWT. The `Startup.cs` file looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SlidingExpiration = true;
        cfg.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        cfg.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
        cfg.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        cfg.SaveToken = true;
        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });

[...]

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder() //makes every controller an every action requiring authorization except if labled by [AllowAnnonymous]
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
.AddViewLocalization(
    options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
.AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

So, as you see, cookie authentication is the main use, and every function which I want to use over the Bearer API, I annotate as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]/")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public ActionResult GetUserDetails()
{
    ...
}
```

This works well for a few months already from different .NET applications and of course from postman. But now I want to connect an Android app (using Java and retrofit) and none of the functions work, even though I pass a valid token as `Authorization` parameter in the HTTP request. As soon as I remove the `Authorize` annotation and replace it with `AllowAnonymous` it works and here comes the strange part: *I can see the `Authorization` parameter in the request header.*

Here some screenshots:

Function called from Postman with `Authorization` active - returning successfully:
[image: From postman]

Function called from android app with `Authorization` active. The controller action is not even being hit but instead the request is redirected to the login page of the CMS (BTW, same thing happens, when I take the token from the postman to the android app and run the request with the very same token which I use for postman):
[image: From Android app with auth]

Now when I remove the `Authorize` attribute on the controller and add a `AllowAnonymous` instead, it works like a charm, but I can see that even though the header contains the `Authorization` attribute, the user shows up as unauthenticated:
[image: From Android app without auth]

I am stuck on this for hours already, I tried to change a few things in the `Startup.cs` file, I read a ton of articles about retrofit, oAuth2, Bearer etc. but unfortunately couldn't find any help so far.

So to me this behavior looks quite strange and my question is, whether I am missing something here, any special information in the header except for the `Authorization` or whatever?
Any input would be much appreciated.

### Edit 1:

Here is the code of the Java (Android) app:

```
//Endpoint
public interface TradeEndPoint {
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
    @GET("Trade/getAllActiveItemsApi")
    Call<List<TradeItem>> getAllActiveItems(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl.getStringValue())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();


TradeEndPoint te = retrofit.create(TradeEndPoint.class);

final Call<List<TradeItem>> getItems = te.getAllActiveItems("Bearer " + getAccessToken(context));
getItems.enqueue(new Callback<List<TradeItem>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<TradeItem>> call, Response<List<TradeItem>> response) {
        TradeItemsLoaded til = (TradeItemsLoaded) fragment;
        til.onTradeItemsLoaded(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<TradeItem>> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

The function `getAccessToken(context)` returns the token as a string.

Here is a screenshot of the fiddler session.
[image: Fiddler Android]
This is from the android app

[image: Fiddler Postman]
This is from Postman (or an equivalent extension for Firefox called RESTer)

So yes, there are differences in the header, but which of them do matter, if any?

Comment: Can you share the code of android app which calls the API?

Comment: You shared 2 strings of code from your app, it's hard to find where the issue is, but  I recommend to check raw request body. are you sure that your code of android app is really send  token in the header? You can use Fiddler or Charles to sniff your traffic from the app, in this way you can see raw request that's sending from the app, and check that header is included to the request.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've added code and screenshots to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In the `Startup.cs` file there is the following expression:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddViewLocalization(
        options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Turns out that the authorization filter does work when working with postman and .NET, but for some reason makes trouble when Bearer authentication is being used from an android app.

I removed this, now it looks like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(
        options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Now I need to annotate every controller with `[Authorize]` but at least it works (maybe you could get the authorization filter work with android as well, but I am not using it anyways, so it's not much of a big deal).